# Permission Denied Error with Starting Nodeos

Tags: keosd

I am completely new to blockchain in general and to EOS blockchain. So I am following the official tutorial up to [Step 1.2](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/development-environment/start-your-node-setup/#step-12-start-nodeos), and that is where I encountered the error: bash: nodeos.log: Permission as seen in the image here [image], I preceded each of the commands with sudo and reran the commands but still getting the same error as seen here: [image]

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Let me break it down for you
In above command only nodeos is the command rest of lines are what we call flags or config options. Flags are a way to set options and pass in arguments to the commands you run. Commands you run will change their behavior based on what flags are set In above command
nodeos (this is main command)
-e (flag)
-p (flag)
--plugin (extra option to enable a plugin)
.
.
.
and so on
Now you only need to put sudo before the main command(not before every flag to make it run with root permission) that is nodeos so in above case only before first line
Check more detail about command you are running [here](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/usage/nodeos-configuration)